# Shap values associated to missing features

Tags: missing-data, shapley-value, explainable-ai

I have a model trained with Xgboost on some training data X_train, described by 10 features (x$_{1}$,...,x$_{10}$) and some of them might exhibit some missingness, i.e. some x$_{i}$ = NaN. This is ok for training a model like Xgboost as it can handle missing entries. Then, I want to tackle the explainability of the model via SHAP, specifically via Tree Shap, in order to calculate the Shap values on a held out/test set X_test:

```
# Tree explainer object
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)

# Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```

What is the meaning of individual Shap values for missing/NaN entries in X_test? If a feature x$_{i}$ = NaN should its Shap value be zero?